# Hadoop CustomInputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to custom split a csv file into objects in hadoop and then have the list of objects as input to the mapper. I am not sure if hadoop's mapper can take objects as input ? Can you please let me know if its possible.

Thank you for your response Praveen. That really helps. I followed the tutorial and it helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom InputFormat should be good in this scenario. Here is a [tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#inputformat) on creating the same. The K or V can be assigned the object which is passed to the mapper. It doesn't really matter weather it's a K or V.